# iOS app leading to electrical earbud mic cut out?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, hardware

this is one of the weirdest things I have ever come across, I had to ask here though it's not strictly about specific code...

I have written an iOS app (min target 9.0) and am testing on an iPhone 6s. What's the issue? I believe that the app is causing the microphone on my Apple earbuds to stop working after about 24-36 hours of normal usage. I appreciate this sounds nuts. Here's my rationale:

Observed behaviour:

With the app installed on my 6s via tethered Build, the following problem occurs (have tested sequence at least 5 times)

1. For the first 12-24 hours, no problem
2. during the next 12 hours at some point when I make or receive a call with my earbuds plugged in, the microphone stops working - I pick up a call on screen and I can hear the calling party but they can't hear me, same if I dial them..
3. another issue which manifests concurrently is with an inbound call, the inbound ringtone coming out of the phone speakers is quite clearly audible crackling as if it's on the verge of distortion or there is some sort of electrical interference issue
4. If I pick up or make a call and this problem has manifested, it will continue to do so, but if on the call connecting I activate the speakerphone button onscreen and immediately deactivate it, the problem vanishes and the microphone starts working again!!
5. If I have powered up the phone having deleted my app, this problem does NOT occur

So, to recap, this issue only manifests if my app is present on my iPhone.

Until a about 3 months ago I was developing (and using in daily life) on an iPhone 5s and did not have this issue.

I have not added any more cocoapods or other capabilities to the app in that time.

I cannot think of what useful code to post, but perhaps the following is useful:

List of pods:
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GooglePlacePicker'

pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
pod 'Stripe/ApplePay'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'Parse',  '1.12.0'
pod 'Branch'

Other aspects of the app:

- uses background location services / significant location change monitoring to restart the app in the background after a power off - location services switch off after, say, 20 minutes. This is fundamental to the functionality but it has the by product that the app always restarts after a power down restart.

I can't think of what else to describe. I am convinced my app is causing the issue, but searching far and wide on www I cannot find anything I can relate this to, and even suggesting it feels illogical.

Thank you in advance for ideas!

Comment: Have you checked your location monitoring background task for memory leaks?
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html

Comment: @TheBasicMind thanks, I will - do you have any particular reason for suggesting the location monitoring background task as a culprit other than the fact it is running in the background over a long period?

Comment: Harris - No. Just reasoning if due to the event driven async model calls or checks are made back to the app layer for sound or bluetooth there might in some way be a dependency on timely execution of some app level code on the same threads as where there has been an overallocation of resources, or memory leaks which are cause things to snarl up in a way that breaks phone audio. Just speculation based on "how the hell might that occur?"